# JDBC connection to mySQL RDS instance in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-rds, private, subnet

We are trying to find out ways to make a JDBC connection to a SQL Server hosted in a private EC2 instance or a private subnet.
Basically, we have an Excel-based small BI report that connects to an On-Prem SQL server and we want to move that DB to cloud and just switch the end points.

There is a lot of information out there about SSH connections to a private subnet RDS SQL server through bastion hosts etc, but I have not found anything related to direct connection.

Due to the infra set up, VPN and direct connect is not possible to use and the users will be directly connecting to private RDS instance over a public internet.

Comment: For a direct connection you can either use a VPN or you can use something like privatelink to connect your VPC to your on-prem.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for your reply.. I forgot to put this in my question.. Direct connect and VPN are not possible for us... Essentially, we are looking for a solution that allows a secure connectivity to an RDS instance in a private subnet over a public internet.

Comment: I also noticed that all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not onlly a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances of your issues being actually answered.

Comment: @Marcin apologies I had no idea if there is an option to accept the answers as well...

Comment: Yes, you can go to your past questions, check which got helpful answers, and press "tick" symbol under up/down vote buttons.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Hello Marcin.. I have suggested the link above to my technical team working on it. I will get back to you ASAP once we have the final solution in place.

Answer (score 3):

> I have not found anything related to direct connection.

Without VPN or Direct Connect, direct connection is **not possible**. Your RDS is in private subnet, as there is no direct internet connectivity to it - thus the name "private".

If you don't want to use VPN and/or don't have Direct Connect, then the only option is to use **ssh tunnel** through a bastion host as explained by AWS:

- [How can I connect to my Amazon RDS DB instance using a bastion host from my Linux/macOS machine?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/)

Comment: Actually we are migrating Db servers to cloud... currently the users have VPN to the On Prem data center... and Data Center as a direct connect with AWS. However, in future, the data center will be shut down and the expectation is to securely connect Power BI or even excel based BI tools directly over the internet to a private RDS instance

Comment: @Hadooplearner VPN would be best I think.

Comment: @Hadooplearner One other posibility that could be considered is [proxying your traffic](https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-make-rds-in-private-subnet-accessible-from-the-internet/) through NBL. Such solution is possible, but requires a bit of setup and future maintenance.

Comment: As I said, there wont be a VPN connection as once migration to AWS is done, expectation is that people will use their BI tools with a connection to private RDS instance over a public internet. Bastion host is an option but that has been ruled out as the users wont be SSHing but they will be directly connecting to the DB using a connection string

Comment: @Hadooplearner Direct connection is not possible. Forget about it if your rds is private. You need proxy through something public.

Comment: The mydata hack link is interesting...In the option 1, if implemented as is, do you see any security risk?  I have sent that link to my architecture team as to me it sounded promising. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Hadooplearner RDS ip is not static. So you would need to design automation to check the IPs, register them with NLB, account for db fail-overs, read instances, etc.